# Pull data only from specified fieldsets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple fieldsets within a form which have individual input/select elements and the following JS/jQuery to process the elements on save.

```
var form = {};

$('fieldset').each(function() {
  var fieldsetId = this.id; var fieldset = {};
  $('#'+fieldsetId+' input:checkbox, #'+fieldsetId+' input:radio').each(function() {
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    fieldset[name] = $(this).val();
  });

  $('#'+fieldsetId+' select').each(function() {
    ...
  }

  form[fieldsetId] = fieldset;
});
```

The data is being read. The problem is with multiple fieldsets. Each successive fieldset is overwriting the last and using all previous input values as well.

Currently, the processed data returned looks something like:

```
first-fieldset (object)
  key:2
  textbox:"value"
  select:"value"
second-fieldset (object)
  key:2
  textbox:"value"
  select:"value"
```

Where it should be:

```
first-fieldset (object)
  key:1
  textbox:"value"
second-fieldset (object)
  key:2
  select:"value"
```

I have a very strong suspicion it's in the way the fieldset elements are being selected but everything I've tried results in either the same format or no data at all.

Comment: @PSL No the ids are like the data returned (first-fieldset, second-fieldset) and so on...

Comment: Where is fieldset defined?

Comment: @PSL Within the {...} code I left out. I'll add a bit in there.

Comment: Still lot of assumptions to make.. Can you prepare a fiddle with the markup and this code. shouldn't be hard i guess?

Comment: It looks like you forgot the `var fieldset` declaration or had put it in the wrong place. Can you show us your actual code, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jdR3V/1/

But it fails as you describe if you put the `var fieldset = {};` outside of the `.each()` call.

---

Also, you can make a few improvements to readability and performance
(*by not using `$()` for properties that are directly accessible, and also caching a reference to a jquery object with the `fieldset` element and using that to find the input elements instead of multiple dynamic selectors*)

```
var form = {};
$('fieldset').each(function() {
  var self = $(this),
      fieldset = {};

  self.find('input:checkbox, input:radio').each(function() {
    fieldset[this.name] = this.value;
  });

  self.find('select').each(function() {
    ...
  }

  form[this.id] = fieldset;
});
```

Comment: Indeed the code I had differed in that I reset fieldset every iteration and instead of just initializing it.